# ListPlot and ColorFunction

Tags: plotting

I've been searching for the use of ColorFunction as an Option for ListPlot, but haven't found anything about it in the documentation. When trying the code

```
ListPlot[
 RandomReal[5, {10}]
 , ColorFunction -> Hue[#1, #2, 1] &
 ]
```

I get the error message

```
ListPlot::nonopt: "Options expected (instead of ColorFunction->Hue[#1,#2,1]&) beyond position 3 in ListPlot[{2.14801,2.18933,<<6>>,3.48,0.566812},ColorFunction-><<1>>&]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules."
```

Is it possible, and if so, how, to use ColorFunction with ListPlot? What are the arguments of the function, then?

Thanks for all help, as always!

Comment: The problem here is that you haven't used parentheses to group the function. It should be `ColorFunction -> (Hue[#, #2, 1]&)`. See [Parentheses in pure functions: # & vs. ( # &)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13120) and [Using several anonymous functions mixed together](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3912) for more info. Regarding your actual question, `ListPlot` doesn't accept a `ColorFunction` without `Joined -> True` (or `ListLinePlot`). Your solution is to use either of these and convert the lines to points as in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1327)

Comment: Either way, it's a duplicate of one of these — you can decide which :)

Comment: @rm -rf: Thanks for the link, that's great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs for the [`ColorFunction` option to `ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html#1753745612):

> `ColorFunction` requires at least one dataset to be `Joined`

```
{ListPlot[Sinc[Range[0, 10, 0.1]],
          ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[x]]],
 ListPlot[Sinc[Range[0, 10, 0.1]],
          ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[x]], Joined -> True]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This appears to have changed in v12.0 -- now both give rainbow colors.