# Distinguishing slots in a function mapping Position across a list

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Suppose that I have a list `myList` that has more than one level.  Here is an example of such a "data structure":

```
myList = {{10, "c"}, {20, "a"}, {30, "b"}};
```

Now suppose that I have a list of characters, called `charList`:

```
charList = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

I want to use `Position` to find the positions of the `charList` characters in `myList`.  Of course, I can do this manually -- by calling `Position` for each character in `charList`:

```
Position[myList, _?(#[[2]] == "a" &), {1}, Heads -> False]
Position[myList, _?(#[[2]] == "b" &), {1}, Heads -> False]
Position[myList, _?(#[[2]] == "c" &), {1}, Heads -> False]
```

> {{2}}
>
> {{3}}
>
> {{1}}

And, of course, I can shorten this process by using `Table` to call `Position` repeatedly:

```
Table[
 Position[myList, _?(#[[2]] == charList[[i]] &), {1}, Heads -> False], 
{i, 1, Length[charList]}]
```

> {{{2}}, {{3}}, {{1}}}

But, is it possible to shorten the code even more by using `Map`?  (I often find `Map` more convenient and easier to read than `Table`.)  My initial thought was to do something like this:

```
Map[
 Position[myList, _?(#[[2]] == # &), {1}, Heads -> False] &,
charList]
```

but I get undesired output:

> {{}, {}, {}}

I think that I have failed to distinguish between the two different `#` slots, which refer to two different things (they refer to different `&`s).  How can I distinguish the two `#` so that I can `Map` `Position` across `charList`?

Comment: Even with `Table` it can be quite neater `Table[Position[myList, {_, i,___}, {1}, Heads -> False], {i, charList}]`

Comment: Since there is nice answer this is a comment how to deal with those slots ambiguity (not neat, just straightforward) `Map[Function[x, 
  Position[myList, _?(#[[2]] == x &), {1}, Heads -> False]], charList]`

Comment: p.s. [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38023/5478)

Comment: Another related question, in fact [my own very first question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/using-several-anonymous-functions-mixed-together).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shorter:

```
Position[myList, {_, #}] & /@ charList
```

Since I feel that the answer is a little short, here's another way:

```
charList /. MapIndexed[Last@# -> First@#2 &, myList]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the OP's original form, distinguish the `charList` parameter using `Function`:-

```
myList = {{10, "c"}, {20, "a"}, {30, "b"}};

charList = {"a", "b", "c"};

Map[
 Function[x, Position[myList, _?(#[[2]] == x &), {1}, Heads -> False]],
 charList]
```

> {{{2}}, {{3}}, {{1}}}

Answer (score 1):

Although I think Anon's:

```
Position[myList, {_, #}] & /@ charList
```

is the neatest, here is  an approach using `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
fun[u_, v_] := 
 Module[{c = 1}, Join @@ Reap[Sow[c++, Last@#] & /@ u, v, Rule][[2]]]
```

For example:

```
fun[myList, charList]
```

yields:

> {"a" -> {2}, "b" -> {3}, "c" -> {1}}

or a list with multiple characters, e.g.

```
test={{10, "c"}, {20, "a"}, {30, "b"}, {1, "a"}};
```

then

```
fun[test,charList]
```

gives:

> {"a" -> {2, 4}, "b" -> {3}, "c" -> {1}}