# Problem with slot in If statement

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I am struggling with slots, In this case I have a function int which gives either true or false. When it gives true, I want

```
Select[interest, (DateList[#[[1, All]]] === #)&]
```

to be applied however as you can see this does not work because of the slots. Problem is that I want the slot in function `int[#]` to be the same as the slot behind ===. How can I overcome this problem?

```
 If[int[#], Select[interest, DateList[#[[1, All]]]& === #], 
    2 {False}] & /@ fasteDatoer]
```

Simple example

Lets say that when first applied it states int[james], which is true. I then want it to `Select[interest, DateList[#[[1, All]]]& === james.`

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @ALEXANDER [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/using-several-anonymous-functions-mixed-together) question will probably help you.

Comment: Not so easy without a sample data. Please provide a minimal sample.

Comment: It would b extremely helpful  to provide a small toy example. As Kuba has advised you can deal with ambiguities of multiple slots by using `Function[x,...]`. If this does not resolve your issue an example would help.

Comment: is it the int[#] that needs to be anonymous or is it the DateList[#[[1, All]]]&?