# Combination of Scan[] and MapIndexed[]. Using an expression with slots corresponding to different functions

Tags: pure-function, slot

If I want to use slots corresponding to different function, how can I dod that. For example:

```
 Scan[MapIndexed[(#1+#2)*#3&,{"a","b","c"}],Range[5]]
```

where I want #3 corresponds to elements in Range[5], but obviously it gives me errors.
How can I pass #3 to the next function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the alternative form of anonymous functions with named parameters:

```
Scan[Function[{x}, MapIndexed[Print[(#1 + #2) x] &, {"a", "b", "c"}]], Range[5]]
```

The old question of mine, [Using several anonymous functions mixed together](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/using-several-anonymous-functions-mixed-together), comes to mind. It also deals with this issue, although in a different context.